Why I'm getting artifacts with normals of exported mesh?
I've created mesh and exported it in unreal engine 5, where I'm getting strange artifacts like this:


when in Blender it looks okay:


I thought the problem could be in normals, but looks like there is no problem with it:

Can you help me to find out the reason of that artifacts?
I'm using Blender 3.6.10 and can't use the latest version, because "send to unreal" addon doesn't work with it.
My .blend file:


Re-opened awaiting self-acceptance, of a 'stub' answer... future readers will see this is not a Blender problem.

Oh, seems like it's problem with nanite option in unreal engine. So, I suppose question is not related to Blender forum.

Hello, Sergey.. Glad you've found the problem ...  you seem confident that this is not a Blender issue, which has the side-effect of making your question off-topic on Blender SE. Nothing personal, but your post doesn't belong here. If you find otherwise, don't hesitate to edit for a re-open. (Thanks for a well-constructed question)

Hello, @RobinBetts. No offense taken. I just want to say, this question is still related to Blender -> UE5 pipeline, so if somebody will face the same problem, he will know where is problem exactly. But I'll prefer to leave decision to you. Should I delete this question?

It's a problem at the Unreal end, in a pretty specialized treatment of geometry for rendering, with no Blender fix. If you have  a fix, I guess that should be published to the Unreal community. On the other hand, if you accept your own 'not a Blender problem' answer, then it will do the archive no significant  harm, slight clutter, but ... future searchers will move on quickly  So, OK, give yourself a tick, and we're done.

@RobinBetts if you think the question is well formed, why not upvote it? :) Cheers

Hi. @MarkusvonBroady .. I thought that was moot, because the post would be closed.. but yes, thanks. This is a funny one. On balance for the archive, paradoxically, Sergei has made a fair point: it is useful for folks to know that the Q is 'off-topic', and usefulness is the aim.
